# How to rotate photos in a div in django-cms

Tags: jquery, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-cms

i want a div in a page where i can rotate the images. Images are to be stored by backend.

so basically there is two things that i want to do using 3.X django-cms.

1. add multiple images. which i think will be stored in photos_table or some_appname_table.
2. want to show those uploaded images by rotating each in a div in frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by saying "rotate" you mean have a slideshow displaying successively your pictures, you can use a plugin like [Aldryn-gallery](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-gallery).

There's also the old [cmsplugin_gallery](https://github.com/centralniak/cmsplugin_gallery) plugin if you don't want to use [filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer) but it might be not compatible with django-cms 3